# Deploying an asp.net website on DomainHut.com hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deployment

I've called their tech support 3 times this morning and spent over $50 in long distance and have had no results. I was wondering if anybody here has deployed an ASP.NET website with `DomainHut.com`'s hosting services.

I've set up my database on their server correctly, all tables, stored procedures and aspnet schema are there just like on my local machine, and I have changed the connection string to point to the correct server, but when I publish the website using the publisher tool to upload the website to `www.mhn.co/mhnprofessionalservices` but I'm only getting an 500 Internal server error. They have advised me to set `<CustomError Mode="on"/>` in the Web.Config file, and I have `<Compilation debug="false"/>` as well.

I need to get this site launched asap and I'm lost.

Comment: I would suggest that you post your question on ServerFault.com. We're more knowledgeable about the programming side here, and they tend to cover more web server and web hosting questions.

Comment: thanks, I posted my question there, as well.

Comment: Take a look at this : http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/resolving_http_500_server_errors_in_aspnet_and_iis_51.htm

Comment: Also, I would recommend setting `debug="true"` and `CustomError Mode="off"` for a minute or two and see if you can see the "real" error message (if not, go ahead and revert them). If you are able to log on to the hosting machine (probably not, but if you do have access), do that, and view the page from the machine's browser, it should give you more details.

Comment: This is going to sound a little silly, but I'd also make sure that you uploaded your website to the correct place. Sometimes hosted server environments have weird folders and things need to be "just so".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've been able to narrow the problem down a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313886/a-name-was-started-with-an-invalid-character-error-processing-resource its something on my end, not the hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with displaying the site was caused by the wrong version of .net, the server needed to be upgraded from 1.1 to support 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5. Thanks for your suggestions!