# A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource

Tags: xml, asp.net, publishing

Here is the exact error I'm getting when I try to launch my default.aspx file from the published folder. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MHNProServices/Default....

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ProServices.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused because I needed to run the website from an IIS server, instead of launching it directly from the folder I published it to. Oops.