# A name was started with an invalid character error while accessing web service through IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I created a web service project by Visual Studio 2010 , and I tested in Visual Studio by Debugging its working good,and after that i added a virtual directory in IIS when I tried to access it via localhost I got an error message like

```
A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'http://localhost/service/Service1.svc'. Line 1, P...

<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfRest.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs"%>
-^
```

I checked ASP.NET version in properties of my virtual directory and i changed it to 4.0.30319 still im unable to correct my error.

So what could be the error in my case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### [A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322907/1115937)
>
> This issue was caused because I needed to run the website from an IIS server, instead of launching it directly from the folder I published it to. Oops.

> ### [A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource ‘http://localhost/ursite/’. Line 1, Posi… SOLVED](http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/a-name-was-started-with-an-invalid-character-error-processing-resource-httplocalhostursite-line-1-posi-solved/)
>
> When multiple versions of the .NET Framework are executing side-by-side on a single computer, the ASP.NET ISAPI version mapped to an ASP.NET application determines which version of the common language runtime (CLR) is used for the application. The ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe) allows an administrator or installation program to easily update the script maps for an ASP.NET application to point to the ASP.NET ISAPI version that is associated with the tool. The tool can also be used to display the status of all installed versions of ASP. NET, register the ASP.NET version that is coupled with the tool, create client-script directories, and perform other configuration operations.

Comment: thanks for your solution Mr.John i tried that but still im getting the same error message,you have any advanced solution for that if so please comment back.